# Encrypt a file in Android then decrypt it in PC

Tags: android, encryption, public-key-encryption

I want to collect data and write in a encrypted file using public key (in Android). Then I send file to PC to read. In my PC I need to create an application to decrypt the file too. How can I do and how to share key securely?

Answer (score 0):

If you have encrypted file using Public key, file can be decrypted only using associated Private key. It is also called as Asymmetric Encryption. But sending your application private key out of application context will be a severe security breach. Public keys are meant to be shared publicly, not the Private Key.

In your case you can encrypt your file on android device using PC/Sever public key, send it to  server and decrypt at server/PC using PC's Private key. This would be the only best solution.